# Which is more secure to access a VMware Windows VM : VMware Remote console or RDP+Remote Desktop Gateway

Tags: windows, rdp, vmware

Without knowing more details, I can't suggest to our security guy that we should use RDP along with a Remote Desktop Gateway.

One person says to that VMware Remote Console is more secure than using RDP with an X.509 certificate but another says the opposite.

Which is more secure?

Answer (score 0):

Both [VMware Remote console](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=%22VMware%20Remote%20console%22) & [Remote Desktop Gateway](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=%22Remote%20Desktop%20Gateway%22) have had severe vulnerabilities, so in that sense neither. Managing servers remotely requires defense in depth. You did not mention where you are accessing the servers from. Assuming the worst, you should not expose either directly to the Internet. Instead, have multiple layers of protection, including:

- Using the remote management protocols over VPN.
- Having separate authentication methods or even accounts for the VPN and for the VM management.
- Requiring MFA.
- If possible, requiring physical access is always more secure than any remote control. If managing virtual machines is not a everyday task, access to the console could be further limited with a firewall or a proxy that requires an extra level of authentication.